# How to add an e4 eclipse part into Show View dialog

Tags: eclipse, dialog, e4

I'm developing an eclipse plugin using e4 technologies intended to be run in Eclipse IDE.

How can I add my part (defined as 'PartDescriptor' in fragment.e4xmi file in my plugin) into the "Show View" dialog tree (main menu > Window > Show View > Other ...) ?

Based on examination of [org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.internal.copy.ViewContentProvider#createChildren](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/swt/internal/copy/ViewContentProvider.java?id=54a02ed6b491f28b25831d516268bffa99b4f657#n78) source code and based on examination of PartDescriptors of other parts using [Live Application Model](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-4-tools-application-model-editor) part I tried to add following tags to my PartDescriptor on Supplementary tab:

- `View`
- `categoryTag:MyGroup`

However, it doesn't work for me. I use Eclipse 4.3 and e4 0.14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible, says Thomas Schindl at
 http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/499424/

> Hello.
>
> How can I add my part (defined as 'PartDescriptor' in fragment.e4xmi
>   file in my plugin) into the "Show View" dialog tree (main menu >
>   Window > Show View > Other ...) ?
>
> Based on examination of
>   org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.internal.copy.ViewContentProvider#createChildren
>   source code and based on examination of PartDescriptors of other parts
>   using Live Application Model part I tried to add following tags to my
>   PartDescriptor on Supplementary tab:
>
> View categoryTag:MyGroup
>
> However, it doesn't work for me. I use Eclipse 4.3 and e4 0.14.
>
> Thans for answers.

---

> I don't think this is the class making up the Show View ... content in
>   the compat layer which is constructed from IViewDescriptors IIRC.
>   Hence if you contribute through a fragment it can't show up there.
>
> Tom

Answer (score 3):

It's possible in 4.6.3 (and possibly before that).

You still need the `View` tag, but `categoryTag` apparently has been deprecated. Instead, there now is a *Category* field in `MPartDescriptor`, which can be set via the Eclipse e4 model editor:

[image: Eclipse e4 model editor screenshot]

Comment: That is so great! Thank you very much for this answer!!! It works!